# Константное поле для родительского класса

Tags: c#, наследование

я хочу что бы в абстрактном базовом классе `Base` было константное поле которое должно задаваться у каждого потомка `Derived1, Derived2` своим значением.

---

UPD: Забыл спросить: поле должно быть статическим?

---

UPD: Переформулирую вопрос.
Есть базовый класс `В` в котором хочу обязать всех потомков реализовывать статическое поле `size`, которое будет защищено от изменения даже внутри класса. Есть 2 потомка: класс `Х` и `Y`. В классе `X` поле `size` должно равняться 6. В классе `Y` поле должно равняться 10.

Comment: Это противоречит идее константности.

Comment: В качестве альтернативы можно использовать свойство только для чтения

Comment: да, видимо мне нужно только для чтения

Comment: Статические члены класса невозможно перегрузить, поэтому поле/свойство не должно быть и не может быть статическим

Comment: abstract class Base { abstract static size; }; class A: Base {static size = 1;}; class B: Base {static size = 2;}; // как то так я бы хотел. Что бы все производные переменные имели обязательное поле, которое для всего  этого класса неизменна и статическая

Comment: Вы говорите вещи взаимоисключающие. При статике нет никаких потомков.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а в Delphi.NET вроде есть :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72223/discussion-on-question-by-kto-to-----).

Comment: @Qwertiy, как-то неудачно вы перенесли, половина комментариев осталась

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я восстановил самые полезные - почти всегда так делаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Base
{
  public int ConstValue { get; private set; }
  public Base(int aConstValue)
  {
    ConstValue = aConstValue;
  }
}
public class Child1 : Base
{
  public Child1() : base(1)
  {
  }
}
public class Child2 : Base
{
  public Child2() : base(2)
  {
  }
}
```

@andreycha  - А лучше сделать свойство абстрактным.

```
public abstract class Base
{
  public abstract int ConstValue { get; }
}
public class Child1 : Base
{
  public override int ConstValue { get { return 1; } }
}
public class Child2 : Base
{
  public override int ConstValue { get { return 2; } }
}
```

Comment: А лучше сделать свойство абстрактным.

Comment: В последних версиях языка можно вообще сеттер выкинуть у свойства, тогда оно станет "более константным" - его устанавливать можно будет только в конструкторе

Comment: Ну и для краткости: `public override int ConstValue => 1;` :)

Answer (score 5):

Используйте свойство только для чтения:

```
abstract class Player
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

class Bot : Player
{
    public override string Name => "Robot";
}
```